# Google Maps API - Nearby Search requests - PlaceID

Tags: google-places-api

I am calling the following API from Google Maps:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={latitude},{longitude}&radius={radius}&type={type}&keyword={keyword}&key={api_key}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%7Blatitude%7D,%7Blongitude%7D&radius=%7Bradius%7D&type=%7Btype%7D&keyword=%7Bkeyword%7D&key=%7Bapi_key%7D)

and even tried:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={latitude},{longitude}&**fields=place_id**,formatted_address,geometry,name&radius={radius}&type={type}&keyword={keyword}&key={api_key}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%7Blatitude%7D,%7Blongitude%7D&**fields=place_id**,formatted_address,geometry,name&radius=%7Bradius%7D&type=%7Btype%7D&keyword=%7Bkeyword%7D&key=%7Bapi_key%7D)

at the end I got the result of places but the place_id is null, which would give more detailed information about this place...but always null.

Any experience?

Thanks in advance,Csaba

Comment: Can you provide the request with values of the variables except for your API key that gives you a result without the place ID? Because we can't reproduce the issue w/o knowing these.

Comment: Thank you Ricky, you just gave me an idea. I put my request in PostMan and it works fine.
I think the issue is more on the Sprint ResTemplate side.
with the same parameters in RestTemplate from Spring doesn't give the proper result (everything is same but some stupid reason place_id stays null), but if I pass it through Postman then it is fine.
I'll update this channel.